# Member Module / Salesforce Integration

Tags: members, salesforce

Has anyone ever integrated/synchronized the EE Member Module with Salesforce? Have an upcoming project that will likely require synchronization with Salesforce.

The website will be for a member organization and they store all of their members in Salesforce. They need to allow members to login to the website, update their contact info, etc. We'd need to develop a two-way integration/synchronization process.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 6):

It can be done, Salesforce is integration using SOAP - so all you'd need to do is to write an EE Module wrapper for SF which encapsulates the necessary calls.

The API for Salesforce is available [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm) and should identify all the things that you can do with it.

You can either have the data held in EE *and* in SF, or simply write a module which 'pulls' the information down from SF and stores it in EE temporarily for editing before pushing it back to SF when it's saved.

I will say now thats its not an easy 10 minute job - so you either need to be a) extremely confident/proficient or b) able to employ someone who can do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Jack Watkins created an extension to be able "*to carry out the submission of register data to Salesforce in a less intrusive way.*"

You can read all about it here:
http://donebecause.co.uk/entries/integrating_expressionengine_salesforce.

It might be a nice starting point.